# TCP transfer file works when server&client are running on 1 PC but corrupts when running on 2

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, corruption

So I'm trying to make a program which sends a file that I want to print from my client in my main PC, to my 2nd PC that runs the server and that is connected to a printer. 
When I was testing my code I ran the client and server on my main pc and it worked fine. However, when I ran the client on my main PC and the server on my 2nd PC the file was corrupted and I'm not sure why.

Here's my `Listener` (I removed the parts that I thought were unnecessary):

```
void Listener()
{
    //All of these strings and bools are filled correctly I just removed it because its long
    string file="";
    string size = "";
    bool print;

    Socket server = myList.AcceptSocket();

    var output = File.Create(file);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Starting to receive the file");

    int k = 0;
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[long.Parse(size)];
    NetworkStream stm = new NetworkStream(server);

    while ((k = stm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length-read)) > 0)
    {
        read += k;
    }
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    output.Close();
    if (print) { PrintFile(file); }
    server.Close();
    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();            
}
```

Here is the client code (I removed the parts that I thought were unnecessary):

```
void startClient()
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.13"), 27015);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    client.SendFile(file);
    Console.WriteLine("File Sent");
    client.Close();
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there an error or are the clients just unconnected?
Are you sure the ip and the port are right?
Maybe you can use the DNS instead of an ip.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838421/setting-up-a-tcp-ip-client-and-server-to-communicate-over-a-network

Comment: @LaMiy not relevant at all. OP mentions the connection is fine, just that the file becomes corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't apply the `read` offset to the buffer, starting to write at index 0 at every `NetworkStream.Read()` call. On local, or when testing with smaller files, this will work fine as everything will arrive in one `Read()`. On a real network or when handling larger files, you'll find that you need multiple `Read()` calls to read all data.

So change it to:

```
stm.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length-read)
```

You also may want to reconsider reading the entire file in memory at once. You might want to write it to disk in the meantime, especially since allocating large arrays can cause an `OutOfMemoryException` way earlier than you expect.

Also consider using existing networking protocols as opposed to rolling your own. Besides this very basic issue, you're prone to running into many other common socket pitfalls.

Comment: Wow, it worked Thanks! I'm really new to networking, so this stuff is kinda very hard for me but I'm willing to put my time into learning it. Thanks again!